# Trying to add multiple JPanel to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

I am trying to add these two `JPanel` to `JFrame`, however only frame shows and nothing is added. Anyone can help me that what am I missing to add these panels?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class grid_Base extends JFrame {

    JFrame mainp = new JFrame();
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    clickButtons buttons[] = new clickButtons[100];

    public grid_Base() {

        super("Battleship");
        mainp.setSize(800, 1500);
        mainp.setResizable(true);
        mainp.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainp.setVisible(true);

        p.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new clickButtons();
            p.add(buttons[i]);
        }
        mainp.add(p);

        p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new clickButtons();
            p2.add(buttons[i]);
        }
        mainp.add(p2);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Always call `setVisible(true);` last, after you have created your UI
2. `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` as it's default layout, so using `mainp.add(p)` and then `mainp.add(p2)` will hide `p`, as only `p2` will be laid out...
3. Don't extend from `JFrame` (especially since you've already got an instance field of `JFrame`), this only makes it more confusing...
4. Have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others
5. Your second loop is overwriting the contents generated by the first loop, this means that when you try and find a button from the array, you will only be able to find buttons created in the second loop and not the first....

Answer (score -1):

You could make these changes to your code so you can see the panels. Change the values ​​to your requirement.

```
    mainp.getContentPane().setLayout(null); //<=== New line
    p.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
    p.setBounds(10,10,390,1300); //<=== position of panel1
    p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Panel1")); // border
    mainp.add(p);
    ....
    p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
    p2.setBounds(400,10,380,1300); //<=== position of panel2
    p2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Panel2")); //border        
    mainp.add(p2);
```

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify.  Have a look at [Why is it frowned upon to use a null layout in SWING?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing) for more details